# What is the defect in this PHP foreach and JS code

Tags: javascript, php, json, foreach, stringify

Basically I have two separate queries that fetch data from a database and outputs in a HTML table. `$result` is the output of query 1 and `$result2` is the output of query 2.

**DEFECT 1**

This is the php code that outputs to a html table:

```
echo "<table id='table'>";
while($row=pg_fetch_assoc($result2)){echo "<tr>";
echo "<td align='left' width='200'>" . $row['message_date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align='left' width='200'>" . $row['message_text'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align='left' width='200'>" . $row['message_by'] . "</td>";
while($row2=pg_fetch_assoc($result)){
  foreach($row2 as $rslt){
    echo "<td align='left' width='200'>" . $rslt['recipient_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td' align='left' width='200'>" . 0 . $rslt['phone_number'] . "</td>";
  }
}
echo "</tr>";}
echo "</table>"
```

The defect is that where there are, for instance 20 recipients meaning 20 names and 20 phone numbers, all the rows are output 3 to 5 times in the table. For example:

`|some-date|some-text|some-sender|John-Doe|12345|John-Doe|12345|John-Doe|12345|...`

I can confirm there are no multiple entries for any names in the table. Why is this?

**DEFECT 2**
Then there's JS at the bottom if the page that takes all the data from the above table and basically converts it into an object then stringified. It works well only that at the problematic recipient fields above (names and phone numbers), it takes only the very first name and phone, I'd expect the repeated recipients data to be there as well. This is the code:

```
var table = document.getElementById('table');
  var jsonArr = [];
  for(var i =0,row;row = table.rows[i];i++){
       var col = row.cells;
       var jsonObj = {
           message_by : col[2].innerHTML,
           message_date : col[0].innerHTML,
           message_recipients: [{
             phone_number : col[4].innerHTML,
             recipient_name : col[3].innerHTML,
           }],
           message_text : col[1].innerHTML,
           subscriber_name: "myName"


         }
         console.log(jsonObj);

      jsonArr.push(jsonObj);
  }

  var sendString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
  console.log(sendString);
```

What am I doing wrong in the php output to the table and why is the JS not picking up all the recipients data from the table?

**EDIT - more info**

For defect 1, this is what I'm expecting:

```
|message date| sender | recipient-1 name | recipient-1 phone | recipient-x name | recipient-x phone | message | subscriber-name |
|------------|--------|------------------|-------------------|------------------|-------------------|---------|-----------------|
```

and this is what I'm getting (notice the repeated recipient entry, but now it's that way for all recipients. Some 3 times some as much as 5 times):

```
|message date| sender | recipient-1 name | recipient-1 phone | recipient-1 name | recipient-1 phone | recipient-2 name | recipient-2 phone | message | subscriber-name |
|------------|--------|------------------|-------------------|------------------|-------------------|------------------|-------------------|---------|-----------------|
| some date  | Peter  |    John Doe      |    0700100100     |    John Doe      |    0700100100     |    Person 2      |    0700200200     |some text|     my name     |
```

For defect 2, this is what I'm expecting:

```
{
"message_by":"Senders Name",
"message_date":"2017-12-14 13:54:28.876",
"message_recipients":[
{
"phone_number":"0700100100",
"recipient_name":"Person One"
},
{
"phone_number":"0700200200",
"recipient_name":"Person Two"
},
{
"phone_number":"0700300300",
"recipient_name":"Person Three"
}
],
"message_text":"Sample text",
"subscriber_name":"myName"
}
```

And this is what I'm getting:

```
{
"message_by":"Senders Name",
"message_date":"2017-12-14 13:54:28.876",
"message_recipients":[
{
"phone_number":"0700100100",
"recipient_name":"Only The First Person"
}
],
"message_text":"Sample text",
"subscriber_name":"myName"
}
```

Comment: Nesting `$row=` looks dangerous.

Comment: Don't use the same variable for your second while loop

Comment: `it takes only the very first name and phone` - because you only ADD the first name and phone, col 3 and 4 ... second name and phone would be in col 5 and 6, third would be in 7 and 8 - presumably

Comment: can you also post the actual result of **DEFECT 1** and also the example of expected output you want

Comment: Try to `unset($row)` before initialize and use it, especially before the second time you use it.

Comment: @JaromandaX I wouldn't expect to add all columns for something that should be dynamic. Next time I might need only 1 name, another time maybe 20

Comment: @Pratansyah I'm not using the same variable. I'm using `$row as $rslt`

Comment: @Pratansyah Oh, I get it. Let me try

Comment: @Pratansyah I just did that, same result

Comment: @Clint_A you aren't using `$rslt` anywhere inside the loop

Comment: @Pratansyah Sorry, that was a silly mistake on my part. However I just replaced it but now it's outputting unintelligible random characters!

Comment: @Clint_A - so why are you complaining you only get col 3/4 when all you do is read col 3/4

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks, now I see why the JS has only col 3 and 4. That one eluded me.Might you have an ideo on how I can fill the names into one column and the numbers into another column?

Answer (score 0):

another problem in your code that you are not aware yet (call it defect 3) is like this

suppose your `result2` (1st while loop) get 10 rows, and `result` (2nd while loop) gets 10 rows also.

```
|  result2  |      |  result   |
|-----|-----|      |-----|-----|
|  a1 |  b1 |      |  c1 |  d1 |
|  a2 |  b2 |      |  c2 |  d2 |
|  .. |  .. |      |  .. |  .. |
| a10 | b10 |      | c10 | d10 |
```

so the first iteration of your 1st loop will produce the first row, then in that row, you dump all 10 rows of `result` into columns in row 1 of `result2`

then in the second iteration (onward) of the 1st loop, there will be no more rows from the 2nd loop so that it look like this:

```
|  a1 |  b1 |  c1 |  d1 |  c2 |  d2 |  .. |  .. | c10 | d10 |
|  a2 |  b2 |
|  .. |  .. |
| a10 | b10 |
```

Comment: I've edited the question to expound more on the table

Comment: still would result in similar layout if you are looping it like that, why not joining the results from postgre query?

Comment: I see the problem with the HTML table. Might you have an idea on how I can populate the names on one column and the numbers on another column instead of new columns for each.

Comment: I tried but the tables have different data types and different number of colums. I ran into all sorts of problems

Comment: don't you have something in common to link those 2 result?, if not, how do you expect to pair the 2nd row of `result2` with the row from `result`?, there must be a common link

Comment: only foreign key. all other columns have different data types and what not

Comment: if there is a foreign key, then you can join the tables using query, such as `select table1.*, table2.* from table1 inner join table2 on table1.fk = table2.pk` ?